# Linux: Difference between /dev/console, /dev/tty and /dev/tty0

Tags: linux, tty, console

On a Linux system, what is the difference between `/dev/console`, `/dev/tty` and `/dev/tty0`?

What are their respective uses, and how do they compare?

Comment: You may also be interested in [this](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/4132/11750)

Answer (score 133, accepted):

From the [Linux Kernel documentation on Kernel.org](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/devices.html):

```
/dev/tty        Current TTY device
/dev/console    System console
/dev/tty0       Current virtual console
```

In the good old days `/dev/console` was System Administrator console. And TTYs were users' serial devices attached to a server.

Now `/dev/console` and `/dev/tty0` represent current display and usually are the same. You can override it for example by adding `console=ttyS0` to `grub.conf`. After that your `/dev/tty0` is a monitor and `/dev/console` is `/dev/ttyS0`.

An exercise to show the difference between `/dev/tty` and `/dev/tty0`:

Switch to the 2nd console by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>. Login as `root`. Type `sleep 5; echo tty0 > /dev/tty0`. Press <kbd>Enter</kbd> and switch to the 3rd console by pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd>.
Now switch back to the 2nd console by pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>. Type `sleep 5; echo tty > /dev/tty`, press <kbd>Enter</kbd> and switch to the 3rd console.

You can see that `tty` is the console where process starts, and `tty0` is a always current console.

Comment: nice exercise!  Ubuntu locks root, so one way to reproduce this on Ubuntu is: `$ sudo sh -c "sleep5; echo tty0 > /dev/tty0"`

Comment: @SFun28, I always used `sudo -i`, and voila - a root shell.

Comment: one idiom for writing to files that require root privs is echo stuff | sudo tee /dev/tty0 >/dev/null;

Comment: Dammit. When Ī̲ wrote http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/229598/80483 , Ī̲ was unaware of *this* answer!

Comment: @SFun28: if `sudo anycommand` works, then `sudo -i` to go root works too. There is no such thing as a Linux/BSD/Unix where you can’t go root. (Then it wouldn’t be Linux/BSD/Unix anymore.)

Comment: What happens when you write to /dev/console? Does it has anything to do with the kernel console that can be viewed with `dmesg`?

Comment: I have ubuntu 18.04. the command `sleep5; echo tty0 > /dev/tty0` didn't show the string `tty0` on the other terminal

Answer (score 76):

- `/dev/console` is a virtual set of devices which can be set as a parameter at boot time. It might be redirected to a serial device or a virtual console and by default points to `/dev/tty0`. When multiple `console=` options are passed to the kernel, the console output will go to more than one device;
- `/dev/tty[0-N]` (`N` is the highest attributed TTY number, e.g. 63) is one of the virtual consoles you switch to with <kbd>control</kbd>-<kbd>alt</kbd>-<kbd>F1</kbd> and so on;
- `/dev/tty0` is also by default virtual console;
- `/dev/tty` is kind of an alias to the console (physical, virtual or pseudo device, if any) associated to the process that open it. Unlike the other devices, you do not need root privileges to write to it. Note also that processes like the ones launched by `cron` and similar batch processes have no usable `/dev/tty`, as they aren't associated with any. These processes have a `?` in the `TTY` column of `ps -ef` output.

Comment: What do you mean by querying it from this statement "/dev/tty is the console used by the process querying it"?

Comment: @RonVince I mean `/dev/tty` can be a different device, if any, depending on the process that open it. Answer updated.

Comment: Thanks. May I know are processes actually write/read to/from /dev/tty instead of directly to/from device file associated to them?

Comment: @RonVince I'm afraid I'm not sure what you are asking. Could you rephrase it?

Comment: If a user's process wants to show something on the user's monitor, is it by Linux standard the process has to write to /dev/tty? Or is it by Linux standard to directly write to /dev/tty[1, .., N] associated to the process? The same for reading input from tty file (keyboard input). Maybe another perspective for my question is does a process need to know its associated /dev/tty[1, .., N] or just read and write to /dev/tty without knowing its own /dev/tty[1, .., N] because /dev/tty is an alias to /dev/tty[1, .., N] associated to itself?

Comment: @RonVince Opening /dev/tty (not /dev/tty[1,..,n]) is the Unix (and Linux) standard for a process to write something to the user's terminal. Directly writing to whatever other device is non portable, more complex and less reliable. A process doesn't need to know what is the actual device the process terminal is connected to, the kernel knows it already.

Comment: **in short:** tty = alias , console = set , tty3 = virtual con meaning a set also! contradictive!

Comment: *echo this_works > /dev/tty* but the others are all **permission denied** .

Comment: @dotbit Yes. That's what I mean about /dev/tty when I write *Unlike the other devices, you do not need root privileges to write to it.*

Comment: /dev/tty is related to the `controlling terminal` of a process. If a process without a `controlling terminal`, open /dev/tty will fail.

Comment: @LGD Yes, that's what I meant with *processes like the ones launched by cron and similar batch processes have no usable /dev/tty, as **they aren't associated with any**.*

Answer (score 46):

### /dev/console

https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/Documentation/admin-guide/serial-console.rst

On Linux, the kernel console can be configured using the `console=` [boot option](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/admin-guide/kernel-parameters.txt).  Kernel code which calls `printk()` may write messages to it, e.g. when a device is loaded or an error occurs.  These messages are also buffered by the kernel.  (See also [`dmesg`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/dmesg.1.html)).  When a console device is found and started, it receives all the previously buffered messages.

You can pass `console=` multiple times to configure multiple consoles, and messages will be written to all of them.  Apparently you can only select one console of each "type": you can't use both `console=ttyS0` and `console=ttyS1`.

The kernel documentation specifies `/dev/console` as a character device numbered `(5,1)`.  Opening this character device opens the "main" console, which is the last tty in the list of consoles.  The first non-kernel process, called `init` or "PID 1", is started with `/dev/console` connected to standard output, standard error, and standard input.

If none of the consoles are a tty, then opening `/dev/console` returns the error `ENODEV` ("No such device").  The kernel will <del>print</del> log a message, and start `init` regardless.  For an example of a kernel console which is not a tty device, see [`netconsole`](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/networking/netconsole.txt), or my favourite console [the line printer](http://cateee.net/lkddb/web-lkddb/LP_CONSOLE.html).

You can also see a list of tty consoles by reading `/sys/class/tty/console/active`.  [systemd documentation](http://0pointer.de/blog/projects/serial-console.html) points out that the *first* device shown is the main console.  The list is actually in reverse order of the kernel command line.  The [current kernel documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/ABI/testing/sysfs-tty) incorrectly states that the last device shown is the main or "active" console.  For some reason it is possible to poll this file for changes (in case console devices are removed?).

Inside a [`systemd-nspawn`](http://0pointer.de/blog/projects/changing-roots.html) container, the standard `/dev/console` file is replaced with a pseudo-terminal device (PTY).  These would be best described as virtual terminal devices.  They are created dynamically and are also used to implement graphical terminal emulators like GNOME Terminal, and for remote access like `ssh`.

### /dev/tty0

The Linux TTY [device nodes](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/admin-guide/devices.txt) `tty1` through `tty63` are virtual terminals.  They are also referred to as VTs, or as virtual consoles.  They simulate multiple consoles on top of the physical console device driver.  Only one virtual console is shown and controlled at a time.  The active terminal can be switched, e.g. using `chvt`, or Ctrl+Alt+F1 through however many function keys you have.

You can also read and write to the current VT using `/dev/tty0`.  `tty0` is the usual kernel console, e.g. if you did not select one explicitly.  "The system first looks for a VGA card [which is what VTs run on] and then for a serial port".  You can also set the console to a specific VT, e.g. `console=tty1`.

"If you don't have a VGA card in your system, the first serial port will automatically become the console."  A "serial console" like `ttyS0` is probably the most common alternative to `tty0`.  It is not possible to use the VT system on top of a serial console.

### /dev/tty

[`/dev/tty` is one of the three standard device files specified by POSIX](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/146735/does-posix-require-any-devices) (`/dev/` is one of the three directory names specified by POSIX).  Opening it is equivalent to opening the controlling terminal of the current process.  The controlling terminal is set when a process first opens a terminal, [at least on Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/447319/29483).  For example, in `init`, it would refer to `/dev/console`.

Detaching from the controlling terminal is one of the steps traditionally required to start a background process, for example a [system logging daemon](https://debian-handbook.info/browse/squeeze/sect.syslog.html).  The steps to become a background process are horribly intricate, but to be specific, the step which detaches from the controlling terminal is the [setsid](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/setsid.2.html) system call. In more modern systems, the init system e.g. systemd starts the service without any controlling terminal in the first place.

Comment: is it possible to echo into any of these? like echo "where does it come out?" >> /dev/ttt...yyy...

Comment: @dotbit Write a question.  You can link to this answer.  You can also put a temporary comment under here, to send me a link to your question, if you like.