# The console terminal demonstrate by who

Tags: osx, console, who

When I issue the command `who` in a bash terminal:

```
$ who
me   console      2018-11-09 07:13
me   ttys000      2018-11-09 07:13
me   ttys001      2018-11-09 07:13
```

The manual states:

> who - show who is logged on
>   Print information about users who are currently logged in.

I am working on two terminals ttys000 and ttys001.

What does `console` mean in the above output?

Comment: Possibly related: [What is the exact difference between a 'terminal', a 'shell', a 'tty' and a 'console'?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4126/what-is-the-exact-difference-between-a-terminal-a-shell-a-tty-and-a-con)

Comment: Possibly related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/60641/linux-difference-between-dev-console-dev-tty-and-dev-tty0

Comment: Those pointing to Linux questions should note that the questioner is asking about MacOS, and about entries in the ASL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taken from an answer from [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/60641/linux-difference-between-dev-console-dev-tty-and-dev-tty0):

Historically the console was the main physical device used by the System Administrator to control the server, and TTYs were the users' serial terminals attached to a server. Now console and tty0 usually identify the same virtual device.