# Why can't i "find" files *.png

Tags: linux, find

System: Ubuntu 11.04,
regular user account:

> find /usr/share -name *.wav

works okay, but if i do:

> find /usr/share -name *.png

it does not produce any output

How do i change the last command to produce an output, like the first command did?

Comment: Are you really using an OS that [does not receive any updates since 8,5 years](https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2012/10/28/ubuntu-11-04-natty-narwhal-end-of-life-reached-on-october-28-2012/)??

Comment: @pLumo given [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/523463/why-dev-console-for-remote-beep-echo-command#comment967857_523463), doesn't seem unlikely

Answer (score 2):

You have an unescaped `*` in your find. That is handled by the shell before find even sees it, so the difference in output is probably because you're in a directory currently that doesn't have wav files in it (`*.wav` doesn't expand), but you do have png files.

What should work for you is `find /usr/share -name \*.png` or `-name '*.png'`.

Comment: exactly..., your post solved this..., thank you very much.-

Comment: @McErroneous As you're new on this site, please don't forget to click the grey **☑** at the left of  [the answer that is the most useful of all](/help/accepted-answer)!  **;-)**